# Event Replay using TrackingEventProcessor - Axon 3

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I'm following the axon-springboot example shared by Allard (https://github.com/abuijze/bootiful-axon).

My understanding so far is: (please correct me if I have misunderstood some of the concepts)

Events are raised and stored in the event store/event bus (Mysql) (using EmbeddedEventStore). Now, event processors (TrackingProcessors - in my case) will pull events from the source (MySql - right?) and event handlers will execute the business logic and update the query storage and message published to RabbitMQ.

**First question** is where, when and who publishes this message to the RabbitMQ (used by statistics application which has the message listener configured.)

I have configured the TrackingProcessor to try the replay functionality. To execute the replay I stop my processor, delete the token entry for the processor, start the processor and events are replayed and my Query Storage is up-to-date as expected.

**Second question** is, when the replay is triggered and Query Storage is updated, I don't see any messages being published to the RabbitMQ...so my statistics application is out of sync. Am I doing something wrong?

Can you please advise?
Thanks
Singh

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a correction: it is not the Tracking Processor or the updater of the view model that sends the messages to RabbitMQ. The Events are forwarded to Rabbit as they are published to the Event Bus.

The answer to your first question: messages are published by the SpringAmqpPublisher, which connects directly to the Event Bus, and forwards any published message to RabbitMQ as they are published.

To answer your second question, let's clarify how replays work, first. While it's called a "replay", essentially it's more a "reset". The Tracking Processor uses a TrackingToken to remember its progress of processing the Event Store. When the token is deleted (or just not yet available), the Tracking Processor starts processing from the beginning of the Event Store.

You never reply an entire application, just a single (Tracking) Processor. Just imagine: you re-publish all messages to RabbitMQ again, other components are triggered again, unaware of the fact that these are "old" messages, and user-confirmation emails are sent again, orders placed again, etc. etc.

If your Statistics are out of date, it's because they aren't part of the same processor and aren't rebuilt together with the other element. RabbitMQ doesn't support "replaying", since it doesn't remember the messages after delivering them.

Any model that you want to be able to rebuild, should be managed by a Tracking Processor.

Check out the Axon Reference guide for more information: https://docs.axonframework.org/part3/event-processing.html#event-processors

Comment: can you suggest code sample for do rebuild the out of date model.Most of the developer i sow ask this question many ways